# complex exponential integral

Tags: integration

I want to know how to calculate this complex exponential integral$$f=\int \exp\left(2\Re\{z^\ast d\}-|z|^2(\lambda+1)\right) \mathrm{d}z,$$where $z$ is a complex variable, $^*$ denotes the complex conjugate operation, $d$ is a complex constant, $\lambda$ is a real constant, $\Re\{\}$ denotes the real part operation, and $|\cdot|$ is the absolute operation. I also want to know where I can learn to calculate the complex integrals in general.

$\textbf{Update}$: Here I give a few steps that I solved:

First, I let $x=z\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}$, then $\frac{dx}{dz}=\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}$, next we have

\begin{align}
f&=\int \exp{(2\Re{\{\frac{x^*d}{\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}}\}}-|x|^2)} \ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}}\int\exp{(-|x|^2+2\Re{\{\frac{x^*d}{\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}}\}}-\frac{|d|^2}{\lambda+1}+\frac{|d|^2}{\lambda+1})} \ dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}}\int\exp{(-|x-\frac{d}{\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}}|^2+\frac{|d|^2}{\lambda+1})} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\lambda+1)}}\exp{(\frac{|d|^2}{\lambda+1})}\sqrt{\pi}
\end{align}
However, the standard answer from the paper that I follow of this question is $\frac{1}{{(\lambda+1)}}\exp{(\frac{|d|^2}{\lambda+1})}{\pi}$, I don't know where are the mistakes in my steps.

$\textbf{Update}$: I just realize that I ignore the product within the integral, here I just attach the original integral from the paper as follow, I realized the product within the integral will influence the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbkUw.png)

Comment: By "the complex integrals in general", do you have in mind all complex integrals, or the... specific ones? Because there isn't even a general way to do real integrals.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I just want to know the basic rules for the complex integrals, just like for real integral, we will have $\int x^k \ dx =\frac{1}{k+1}x^{k+1}$, so what happens when $x$ is complex or when we have $\int x^* dx$

Comment: You should also tell us what $\ast$ means ... multiplication (as in computer science) or complex conjugate (as in physics) or convolution (as in mathematics) or ... ?

Comment: @GEdgar That $^\ast$ is my fault; I thought it was clearer than the OP's $^H$ as a symbol of complex conjugation.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your comments, I have corrected it now

Comment: So, it is not an indefinite integral?  How about revealing what space you integrate over?

Comment: @GEdgar thank you for your comment. That is also my question because I know from the mathematics course, we usually have the contours for the complex integrals, but when I read the literature on signal processing or telecommunication, there is no such contour notation for the complex integrals...

Answer (score 0):

When we write $\int \dots \;dz$ where $z$ is a complex variable, we usually assume that $\dots$ is analytic in $z$.  If it is not (as here) then there is no nice complex-variable formula for the answer.  You have to revert to writing this as a line integral in the plane $\mathbb R^2$.  And you should show a contour on which to integrate: the integral certainly is **not** simply subtracting something at the endpoints.  So the "indefinite integral" concept is not useful here.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. However, I know this integral from a classic literature in my research area, it does have a solution, but maybe somehow my question format is not very correct..I have gave some steps if you would like to check